# Store the result in a Map in C++ and then iterate it and then print out?

Tags: c++, dictionary, cassandra, libcql

I have started working with `C++ libcql` library for Cassandra.. I am trying to retrieve data from Cassandra using C++ with libcql library..

Whenever I go on the command line using `cqlsh` and do select like this -

```
 select records from profile_user where user_id = '1';
```

I always get the below output on the cql command line and in which `records` column is actually a `map`  in which key is `e1` and value is `HELLO`. In the same way key is `e2` and value is `HELLO` again.. When I created the table in CQL, I created records as the map as I was using collection feature of CQL..

```
 records
--------------------------------
 {'e1': 'HELLO', 'e2': 'HELLO'}
```

**Now Coming to C++ world-**

Now I am trying to retrieve the same thing from the `C++ libcql library`... I will be running the same above select query in C++ and I want to return a map which will have `e1, e2 as the key` and `HELLO as there value inside that map`... It is possible to do it in C++?

```
/**
 * This method will retrieve the data from Cassandra..
 * And then call print_rows method to print it out on the console
 */
void get_attributes(string id){
    try{

        // some code

        //Connection open
        connection_open();

        execute_query("USE testks;");

        //this will give me the result back of the select query
        cql_result_t& result = execute_query("select * from profile_user where key ='"+id+"';");

        // and this is printing it out on the console
        print_rows(result);

        // some code
    } catch (int e){
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Below is the method which will print out the results on the console after running my C++ program -

```
/**
 * This method prints out the result on the console..    *
 *
 */
void print_rows(cql::cql_result_t& result) {
    while (result.next()) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < result.column_count(); ++i) {
            cql::cql_byte_t* data = NULL;
            cql::cql_int_t size = 0;
            result.get_data(i, &data, size);
            std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
            std::cout << " | ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The result that I see on the console after running my above C++ program is something like this -

```
e1HELLOe2HELLO |
```

But what I am looking for is - **Store the result in a Map in C++, in such a way such that key should be `e1 and e2` in the Map.. And the value for them should be `HELLO` in the same Map... And then iterate the Map and print out the result in C++?** Is this possible to do with the current code I have?

If yes, can anyone provide a simple example on this? Thanks...

It is basically a C++ question I guess.. Just retrieve the data and put it into the Map... But the problem I am facing is my background is totally in Java so having little bit hard time to figure out how to do that...

Comment: you must have considered `std::map`, right?

Comment: Yeah.. That's what I was thinking or unorderedmap as well for efficiency as I was reading that unorderedmap is efficient...

Comment: So your only problem is how to pull `result` coming to `print_rows` into a `std::map`, right ?

Comment: Yes, Exactly... But it should be in the way such that in the map - key should be e1 and hello its value.. And again key should be e2 and hello its value again...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cql library, but looks like your `data`, which is `"e1HELLOe2HELLO"` needs to be splitted either using some text parsing or simply using some function from the cql library, and once you get data as id and value, putting them into map is really simple.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance in C++.. So you are saying data will actually have `"e1HELLOe2HELLO" `? If yes, then let's say if we need to split it out using some text parsing then how we are going to identify at what place should we split to get the actual key value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `libcql` and I failed to locate any documentation. Looking at the header for [`cql_result_t`](https://github.com/mstump/libcql/blob/master/include/libcql/cql_result.hpp) indicates that there are functions to determine how many columns there are and how to access them. From the looks of it, you merely copied the demo example which doesn't seem to be a particular good demo. I would start off with refining the `print_result()` function to look something like the below and see what I'd get. My *guess* is that you get a "map" type from your query and you'll need to see how to extract and use the corresponding representation by digging through their headers (unless there is somewhere some documentation). The code below mere extracts a few types and mostly prints that it needs to deal with processing the respective type (assuming it actually compiles):

```
void print_result(cql::cql_result_t& result)
{
    std::size_t const columns(result.column_count());
    while (result.next()) {
        for (std::size_t column(0); column != columns; ++column) {
            cql::cql_column_type_enum type;
            if (result.column_type(column, type)) {
                switch (type) {
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_CUSTOM:
                    std::cout << "todo: process custom type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_ASCII:
                    std::cout << "todo: process ascii type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_BIGINT:
                    std::cout << "todo: process bigint type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_BLOB:
                    std::cout << "todo: process blob type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    std::cout << "todo: process boolean type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_COUNTER:
                    std::cout << "todo: process counter type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_DECIMAL:
                    std::cout << "todo: process decimal type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_DOUBLE: {
                    double value;
                    if (result.get_double(column, value)) {
                        std::cout << "column=" << column << " "
                                  << "double=" << value << "\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "failed to extract double for column "
                                  << column << "\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_FLOAT: {
                    float value;
                    if (result.get_float(column, value)) {
                        std::cout << "column=" << column << " "
                                  << "float=" << value << "\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "failed to extract float for column "
                                  << column << "\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_INT: {
                    int value;
                    if (result.get_int(column, value)) {
                        std::cout << "column=" << column << " "
                                  << "int=" << value << "\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "failed to extract int for column "
                                  << column << "\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_TEXT: {
                    std::string value;
                    if (result.get_string(column, value)) {
                        std::cout << "column=" << column << " "
                                  << "text='" << value << "'\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "failed to extract text for column "
                                  << column << "\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_TIMESTAMP:
                    std::cout << "todo: process timestamp type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_UUID:
                    std::cout << "todo: process uiid type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_VARCHAR:
                    std::cout << "todo: process varchar type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_VARINT:
                    std::cout << "todo: process varint type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_TIMEUUID:
                    std::cout << "todo: process timeuuid type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_INET:
                    std::cout << "todo: process inet type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_LIST:
                    std::cout << "todo: process list type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_MAP:
                    std::cout << "todo: process map type\n";
                    break;
                case cql::CQL_COLUMN_TYPE_SET:
                    std::cout << "todo: process set type\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is not that much documentation.. But this is the github [link](https://github.com/mstump/libcql) for the same libcql library.. Let me compile these and see how it goes..

Answer (score 0):

cql_result_t has a method get_map. Use get_map instead of get_data:

```
cql::cql_result_t *r;
cql::cql_map_t *props = 0;
if (!r->get_map("records", &props)) {
   delete props;
   // throw an error
}

std::auto_ptr<cql::cql_map_t> p(props);
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < p->size(); ++i) {
   std::string key;
   if (!p->get_key_string(i, key))
        // throw an error
   std::string value;
   if (!p->get_value_string(i, value))
        // throw an error
   m.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
}
```