# How to store the result in a Map in C++ and then iterate it and then prints out the result?

Tags: c++, dictionary, cassandra, libcql

I have started working with `C++ libcql` library for Cassandra.. I am trying to retrieve data from Cassandra using C++ with libcql library..

Whenever I go on the command line using `cqlsh` and do select like this -

```
select record_name, record_value from profile_user where user_id = '1';
```

I always get the below output on the cql command line and in which `record_name` and record_value are actually a column of `TEXT datatype which is UTF-8 encoded string`.

```
 record_name | record_value
-------------+--------------
          e1 |        hello
          e2 |        hello
```

**Now Coming to C++ world-**

Now I am trying to retrieve the same thing from the `C++ libcql library`... I will be running the same above select query in C++ and I want to return a map which will have `e1, e2 as the key` and `HELLO as there value inside that map`... It is possible to do it in C++?

```
/**
 * This method will retrieve the data from Cassandra..
 * And then call print_rows method to print it out on the console
 */
void get_attributes(string id){
    try{

        // some code

        //Connection open
        connection_open();

        execute_query("USE testks;");

        //this will give me the result back of the select query
        cql_result_t& result = execute_query("select * from profile_user where key ='"+id+"';");

        // and this is printing it out on the console
        print_rows(result);

        // some code
    } catch (int e){
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Below is the method which will print out the results on the console after running my C++ program -

```
/**
 * This method prints out the result on the console..    *
 *
 */
void print_rows(cql::cql_result_t& result) {
    while (result.next()) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < result.column_count(); ++i) {
            cql::cql_byte_t* data = NULL;
            cql::cql_int_t size = 0;
            result.get_data(i, &data, size);
            std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
            std::cout << " | ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The result that I see on the console after running my above C++ program is something like this -

```
e1 | hello |
e2 | hello |
```

But what I am looking for is - **Store the result in a Map in C++, in such a way such that key should be `e1 and e2` in the Map.. And the value for them should be `HELLO` in the same Map... And then iterate the Map and print out the result in C++?** Is this possible to do with the current code I have?

If yes, can anyone provide a simple example on this? Thanks...

It is basically a C++ question I guess.. Just retrieve the data and put it into the Map... But the problem I am facing is my background is totally in Java so having little bit hard time to figure out how to do that...

I have slightly changed my table design in this question to my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341994/store-the-result-in-a-map-in-c-and-then-iterate-it-and-then-print-out) instead of using collection, now I am using composite keys..

But If I can figure out the solution to my previous question then I will be going with that approach, otherwise I will be going with this approach..

Thanks for the help...

**Update Code:-**

With the below change, it always print out first result twice? Not sure why?

```
void print_rows(cql::cql_result_t& result){
    while (result.next()) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < result.column_count(); ++i) {
            cql::cql_byte_t* data = NULL;
            cql::cql_int_t size = 0;
            result.get_data(i, &data, size);
          //  std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
          //  std::cout << " | ";

        if(!flag) {

        key = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
        flag = true;

        } else if(flag) {

        value = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
        m[key] = value;
        flag = false;
        }

        }

        std:map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it = m.begin();

        for (;it!=m.end(); ++it ) {

        std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

e1 : hello

e1 : hello
e2 : hello
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: My only problem is how to pull the result coming to print_rows into a std::map or unorderedmap whichever is efficient and then iterate it and print out the results..!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store the result in a Map in C++ and then iterate it and then print out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341994/store-the-result-in-a-map-in-c-and-then-iterate-it-and-then-print-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like your keys and values are alternating on each pass,

You can have something like this :

```
bool flag=false;
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
std::string key,value;

void print_rows(cql::cql_result_t& result) {
    while (result.next()) {
         //...
            if(!flag)
            {
                key=reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
                flag= true;   
            }
            else if(flag)
            {
                value=reinterpret_cast<char*>(data);
                m[key] = value;
                flag = false;
            }
           // ....
        }
        //...
    }
```

Now to transverse the map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it=m.begin();

for(;it!=m.end();++it)
  std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
```

Or if you're using C++11 :

```
for(const auto &it:m)
  std::cout << it.first << " : "<< it.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: @POW: Thanks for suggestion and help.. But in your example what is key and value? They never got declared..? And after putting everything in the map how we will be iterating the map? Pardon my ignorance as my background is not in C++.. Thanks for understanding

Comment: @POW: I have updated my question.. Everything is working fine but the only problem is, first key value pair gets printed out twice.. Not sure why? Any thoughts?

Comment: @TechGeeky you should print the map outside your `while(result.next())` loop, also, make sure you don't have keys like `"e1"`, `"e1 "`  or `" e1"` . A space will be considered as new unique key

Comment: Yeah I will make sure about the keys... After moving to while loop.. It works fine.. One more thing I would like to confirm suppose if I have other key value pair in the correct format, then it will get printed out right as the way e1 and e2 are getting printed out now? Just wanted to make sure.. Thanks..

Comment: @TechGeeky yes, as long as you're able to get correct `std::string` from your `data` for keys and values, you can insert any those

Comment: Sure.. make sense now.. Apart from these, do you see any benefit in using unorderedmap as compared to orderedmap here?

Comment: @POW: I also have one more question on C++ on which nobody has replied yet... This is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331921/how-to-deserialize-the-bytearray-from-the-file-using-c-in-proper-way).. See if you can help me out there as well? Thanks a lot..